# LRUCache for integers using dict + linkedlist

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

From leet code question: https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/

> Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU)
>   cache. It should support the following operations: get and put.
>
> get(key) - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the
>   key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1. put(key, value) - Set or
>   insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache
>   reached its capacity, it should invalidate the least recently used
>   item before inserting a new item.
>
> Follow up: Could you do both operations in O(1) time complexity?
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> LRUCache cache = new LRUCache( 2 /* capacity */ );
>
> cache.put(1, 1);
> cache.put(2, 2);
> cache.get(1);       // returns 1
> cache.put(3, 3);    // evicts key 2
> cache.get(2);       // returns -1 (not found)
> cache.put(4, 4);    // evicts key 1
> cache.get(1);       // returns -1 (not found)
> cache.get(3);       // returns 3
> cache.get(4);       // returns 4
> ```

**Code:** Filename: `lru_cache.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class Node:
    def __init__(self, key: int, val: int, prv=None, nxt=None):
        self.prv = prv
        self.nxt = nxt
        self.val = val
        self.key = key

    def __str__(self):
        nx = str(self.nxt)
        return "{}:{} -> {}".format(self.key, self.val, nx)


class LRUCache:
    def __init__(self, capacity: int):
        """
        :type capacity: int
        """
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.cap = capacity
        self.cache = {}
        self.size = 0

    def get(self, key):
        """
        :type key: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if key not in self.cache:
            return -1

        node = self.cache[key]

        if self.first is self.last:
            return node.val

        if node is self.last:
            return node.val

        if node is self.first:
            nxt = node.nxt
            nxt.prv = None
            self.first = nxt
            node.nxt = None
        else:
            # In the middle
            nxt = node.nxt
            prv = node.prv
            node.nxt = None
            prv.nxt = nxt
            nxt.prv = prv

        self.last.nxt = node
        node.prv = self.last
        self.last = node
        return node.val

    def put(self, key, value):
        """
        :type key: int
        :type value: int
        :rtype: void
        """
        if self.get(key) != -1:
            # Already have
            self.cache[key].val = value
            return

        node = Node(key, value)

        if not self.first:
            self.size = 1
            self.first = node
            self.last = node
            self.cache[key] = node
            return

        self.cache[key] = node
        self.last.nxt = node
        node.prv = self.last
        self.last = node
        self.size = len(self.cache)

        if self.size > self.cap:
            # Need to remove
            first = self.first
            nxt = first.nxt
            nxt.prv = None
            self.first = nxt
            del self.cache[first.key]
            self.size = self.cap

    def __str__(self):
        return "LRUCache:: {}".format(self.first)


def _test():
    cache = LRUCache(2)

    cache.put(1, 1)
    cache.put(2, 2)
    assert cache.get(1) == 1  # returns 1
    cache.put(3, 3)  # evicts key 2
    assert str(cache) == "LRUCache:: 1:1 -> 3:3 -> None"
    assert cache.get(2) == -1  # returns -1 (not found)
    cache.put(4, 4)  # evicts key 1
    assert str(cache) == "LRUCache:: 3:3 -> 4:4 -> None"
    assert cache.get(1) == -1  # returns -1 (not found)
    assert cache.get(3) == 3  # returns 3
    assert cache.get(4) == 4  # returns 4
    assert str(cache) == "LRUCache:: 3:3 -> 4:4 -> None"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test()
```

**What I want reviewed:**

1. How pythonic the code is? How can I improve it.
2. Is there any area I can optimise performance ? (This passes all tests on leet-code)
3. Readability improvements?
4. Structure of the code file? Can we place things better?

You are welcome to be strict and brutal.

**Additional info:**

- I've used **black** to format code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use more abstract data types

In the current implementation two behaviors are mixed together:

- Caching
- Linked list manipulation

It would be better if the linked list manipulation was encapsulated in a dedicated abstract data type. Then `LRUCache` could use an instance of it, and perform operations that have nice descriptive names like `append_node`, `delete_node`, instead of blocks of nameless code. It will reveal more clearly the implemented logic of both the caching and linked list behaviors, and be more intuitively readable.

#### Avoid unclear side effects

At first glance I found this piece surprising in `put`:

> ```
> if self.get(key) != -1:
>     # Already have
>     self.cache[key].val = value
>     return
> ```

Why `self.get(key) != -1` instead of `key not in self.cache`?
The `self.get` is of course necessary,
for its side effect of moving the node to the end.
This may be subjective,
but I would prefer to have an explicit private method that moves the node,
and call it from both `get` and `put`.
That will make the intention perfectly clear.
Another reason I prefer that is to eliminate using the magic value `-1` more than necessary.